# md5 password confirmation failing

Tags: php, mysql, md5

Yes, I know that md5 is not a good option, and I should rather use password_hash(), but my hosting solution is on php version 5.3.3. Anyway, this is never supposed to be a production environment, just for training purposes, and I will soon change provider.

So I have setup some code, and I can see that the credentials I register, the password in md5 format are logged in the db. But when logging in the same credentials I get my error message I set up, "invalid email or pass"

This is my code:

```
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();
include_once("config.php");
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['signup'])){
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);

$insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name,email,pass)
values(:name,:email,:pass) ");
$insert->bindParam(':name',$name);
$insert->bindParam(':email',$email);
$insert->bindParam(':pass',$pass);
$insert->execute();
}
 elseif(isset($_POST['signin'])){
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $pass = $_POST['pass'];

 $select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' and pass='$pass'");
 $select->setFetchMode();
 $select->execute();
 $data=$select->fetch();
 if($data['email']!=$email and $data['pass']!=$pass)
 {
  echo "invalid email or pass";
 }
 elseif($data['email']==$email and $data['pass']==$pass)
 {
 $_SESSION['email']=$data['email'];
    $_SESSION['name']=$data['name'];
header("location:aeroplane.php"); 
 }
 }
```

So, the signup works fine, then the else if for signing fails. What have I missed here?

-thanks

Comment: `my hosting solution is on php version 5.3.3` You do realize that you're open to a ton of security flaws that were not patched since PHP 5.3 [went EOL almost 3 years ago](http://php.net/eol.php)

Comment: You shouldn't use `md5()` for password storage, you should use the `password_*()` API instead.

Comment: there is the compatibility pack https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat that you can use for php <5.5 - it's even mentioned in the `password_hash()` manual. http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: And just because it bears repeating [MD5 is not secure at all, because it is fast](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)

Comment: @Fred-ii- The compatibility pack requires >= 5.3.7 and he's on 5.3.3

Comment: @Machavity  they can still use crypt/bcrypt http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php - their php version isn't an excuse for using md5 - and it might even still work.

Comment: [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)

Comment: if you intend to go live or are live with this, you **will** get hacked; that's a guarantee that you can take to the bank. Even though you are going to use the accepted answer, md5 is still md5, even though a prepared statement is used.

Comment: No way, this is not at all for production purposes,  just for learning purposes. I am planing to move to a new provider

Comment: Since you care about security it seems, your login code contains sql injections using user and pass directly in SQL, whereas the signin code does use PDO bind parameters API. You should fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();
include_once("config.php");
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['signup'])){
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);

$insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name,email,pass)
values(:name,:email,:pass) ");
$insert->bindParam(':name',$name);
$insert->bindParam(':email',$email);
$insert->bindParam(':pass',$pass);
$insert->execute();
}
 elseif(isset($_POST['signin'])){
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);

 $select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' and pass='$pass'");
 $select->setFetchMode();
 $select->execute();
 $data=$select->fetch();
 if($data['email']!=$email and $data['pass']!=$pass)
 {
  echo "invalid email or pass";
 }
 elseif($data['email']==$email and $data['pass']==$pass)
 {
 $_SESSION['email']=$data['email'];
    $_SESSION['name']=$data['name'];
header("location:aeroplane.php"); 
 }
 }
```

updated  `$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);` in signing code.

You need to use md5 at login time also

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' and pass='$pass'` - I don't know why you used a prepared statement for one, but not the other.

Comment: @Fred-ii- just trying to solve his problem. everything copied from the question.

Answer (score 1):

The password is saved as md5 in the database so you should hash it too on the sign in order to compare it correctly.

Solution:

just change this `$pass = $_POST['pass'];`
 to `$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);`

Your code is basically comparing a non hashed password to a hashed password which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your code and find error after sign in code.
update the code `$pass=$_POST['pass'];` to

```
$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
```